# Выгрузка данных из DataGridView в Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Может кто знает, как можно оптимизировать код, т.к. при выгрузке около 20-30 тыс. строк процесс зависает на достаточно большое время.

```
for (int x = 0; x < DataGrid.Rows.Count; x++) {
    DataGridViewRow row = DataGrid.Rows[x];
    for (int y = 0; y < row.Cells.Count; y++) {
        Excel.Cells[x + 2, y + 1] = row.Cells[y].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Оптимизировать здесь нечего, можно только запустить это в отдельном потоке, чтоб интерфейс не зависал
Либо вот еще одно решение попробуйте: 
[How to export dataGridView data Instantly to Excel on button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182029/how-to-export-datagridview-data-instantly-to-excel-on-button-click)

Comment: @beliy26rus, оригинальный совет...
Про потоки я знаю, но в данном случае, они мне не помогли бы, т.к. процесс так же медленно бы выполнялся. В общем, я сделал через Range, как мне уже подсказали ранее, проверил на 100 тыс. строках - выгрузилось менее чем за 5 сек.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загоняешь все данные грида в массив Variant (ArrayData : Variant), потом копируешь их в эксель, например (delphi):

```
   for i := 2 to (DM.IBQ_main.RecordCount + 1) do
   begin
     ArrayData[i, 1] := DM.IBQ_main.FieldByName('ID_0').AsString;
     ArrayData[i, 2] := DM.IBQ_main.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
     DM.IBQ_main.Next;
   end;

  // Левая верхняя ячейка области, в которую будем выводить данные
  Cell1 := EA1.Cells.Item[1, 1];
  // Правая нижняя ячейка области, в которую будем выводить данные
  Cell2 := EA1.Cells.Item[DM.IBQ_main.RecordCount + 1, 49];
  // Область, в которую будем выводить данные
  Range := EA1.Range[Cell1, Cell2];
  Range.Value2 := ArrayData;
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, идею примерно понял, буду пробовать работать с рэнжем.

Comment: @Владислав24, все получилось с Range! Благодарю еще раз за дельный совет!